# how to use column from model in anther model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have two models the first models is for users and the second is for candidates when I register an account that is done using the first model and when I enter to edit the account  information as the name and date of birth  I need to rewrite this information back knowing that I put it during the account registration, is there a way to modify the second model form to take the information from the first model

the first models :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField




GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', "Male"),
    ('F', "Female"),
    ('O', "Other"),
)
class User(AbstractUser):
    username=None
    email=models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default='1990-01-01')
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES,blank=True)
    picture=models.ImageField(
        upload_to='img/users',null=True,verbose_name=""
    )
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

the secound models :

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from autoslug import AutoSlugField
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from recruiters.models import Job
from django.utils import timezone

CHOICES = (
    ('Full Time', 'Full Time'),
    ('Part Time', 'Part Time'),
    ('Internship', 'Internship'),
    ('Remote', 'Remote'),
)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes', null=True, blank=True)
    grad_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    looking_for = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, choices=CHOICES, default='Full Time', null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user', unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/profile/{}".format(self.slug)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

> can any one help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Override the save method of User model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# custom manager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', "Male"),
    ('F', "Female"),
    ('O', "Other"),
)
class User(AbstractUser):
    username=None
    email=models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default='1990-01-01')
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=GENDER_CHOICES,blank=True)
    picture=models.ImageField(
        upload_to='img/users',null=True,verbose_name=""
    )
    phone = PhoneNumberField()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    objects = UserManager()
    def save(self,**kwargs):
        if not (self.is_staff or self.is_superuser):
            password = self.password
            if password is not None:
                self.set_password(password)
            super(User,self).save(**kwargs)
            name=f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"    
            Profile.objects.create(name=name,dob=self.date_of_birth,user=self) 
            return self
        else:
            return super(User,self).save(**kwargs)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='profile')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    country = CountryField(null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to='resumes', null=True, blank=True)
    grad_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    looking_for = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, choices=CHOICES, default='Full Time', null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='user', unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/profile/{}".format(self.slug)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```